# How can I use cypress import fixture file

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm writing in regard to cypress fixture.
I'm trying to use fixture.incorrectEmail and fixture.incorrectPassword but it doesn't work.
The error is Cannot read property `correctEmail` of undefined

I want to use it as below.

My Fixture file json:

```
{
  "incorrectEmail": "karolina.waterrr@gmail.com",
  "incorrectPassword": "1234777",
}
```

My test file:

```
import fixture from '../../fixtures/data.json'

describe("checkAuthentication", () => {
    before(() => {
        cy.visit("http://localhost:8080")
    })
    it('it should fail if bad email', () => {
        cy.dataTestId("worker-email").type(fixture.incorrectEmail)
        cy.dataTestId("worker-password").type(fixture.incorrectPassword)
        cy.dataTestId("test-button").click()
        cy.dataTestId("test-wrong-message").should("have.text", " wrong email ")

    })
```

my config file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
      "cypress"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Thank you for your help,

Import is correct but console.log(fixture) return undefined, honestly I don't know what is wrong

Comment: can you put `console.log(fixture);` just before where you use it ?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress provides an inbuilt way to access fixtures file into your test. You can read more about it from the [Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture).

```
describe('Test Suite', () => {

  before(function() {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:8080")
  })

  beforeEach(function() {
    cy.fixture('data').then((data) => {
      this.data = data
    })
  })

  it('Test', function() {
    cy.dataTestId("worker-email").type(this.data.incorrectEmail)
    cy.dataTestId("worker-password").type(this.data.incorrectPassword)
    cy.dataTestId("test-button").click()
    cy.dataTestId("test-wrong-message").should("have.text", " wrong email ")
  })
})
```

And remember, If you store and access the fixture data using `this` test context object, make sure to use `function () { ... }` callbacks. Otherwise, the test engine will NOT have this pointing at the test context.

Comment: I think this is correct. Can you link me to the docs to which you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The way to load a fixture on the `this` context is shown [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#this-context)

```
describe("checkAuthentication", function () {

  before(function () {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:8080")
  })

  beforeEach(function () {
    // "this" points at the test context object
    cy.fixture('data').then((user) => {
      // "this" is still the test context object
      this.user = user
    })
  })

  it('it should fail if bad email', function () {

    // Note access via "this.user"

    cy.dataTestId("worker-email").type(this.user.incorrectEmail)
    cy.dataTestId("worker-password").type(this.user.incorrectPassword)
    cy.dataTestId("test-button").click()
    cy.dataTestId("test-wrong-message").should("have.text", " wrong email ")
  })
})
```

But

```
import fixture from '../../fixtures/data.json'
```

works just as well, so I suspect you have just mixed up property names.